# Automate click on button

Tags: c#, ui-automation

I am trying to click a button in an application from a `.Net 7` c# program in windows. The button has only the property `IsLegacyIAccessiblePatternAvailable = true`, which I can see in the windows Inspect.exe. Thus, I did try to invoke the button with:

```
if (button_Create.TryGetCurrentPattern(LegacyIAccessiblePattern.Pattern, out var pattern))
{
  var legacyPattern = (System.Windows.Automation.LegacyIAccessiblePattern)pattern;
  legacyPattern.DoDefaultAction();
}
```

However, I cannot get this to work because `LegacyIAccessiblePattern` is not found with error `CS0103` and `CS0234`. Other methods from `System.Windows.Automation` however are available.

What do I have to do to tell VS to include the correct library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the v3.0 of the Windows Automation API? I found the projects [UIAComWrapper](https://github.com/TestStack/UIAComWrapper/tree/master) and [UIAutomation-Interop](https://github.com/FlaUI/UIAutomation-Interop) that enable the use of classes in olders versions of the API, and they include LegacyIAccessiblePattern. So it might be the case that you trying to use a class that is only available in old versions of the API.

You might want to try to reference the NuGet package for the second one, [Interop.UIAutomationClient](https://nuget.org/packages/Interop.UIAutomationClient) and see if it does the trick.